# Drawing diagonal lines over a textbox in Java

Tags: java, jtextfield

Is it possible to draw diagonal lines over a JTextField (or any other Swing control as well) without just putting a panel over the textbox?

Answer (score 5):

Create a custom JTextField and override the paint() method. Something like:

```
public void paint(Graphics g)
{
    super.paint(g);
    //  do custom painting here
}
```

Note: normally custom painting is done by overriding the paintComponent(..) method of a component. So you could also do:

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
{
    super.paintComponent(g);
    //  do custom painting here
}
```

and the result will be the same because a JTextField does not have any child components added to it. However I suggested using paint(...) because this approach would work if you wanted to paint diagonal lines on a component (like JPanel) that does support child components. Please make sure you understand the difference between the two methods by reading the section from the Swing tutorial on [Custom Painting](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/painting/closer.html).

Or another option would be to create a custom highlighter that draws diagonal lines over the selected text. The [RectanglePainter](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/28/rectangle-painter/) can get you started with this approach.

So you have a couple of different options depending on your requirements.